# What metaphor do you use for the DOM? Does it go "up" or "down"?

Tags: html

When referring to the DOM, do you think of nested elements as being "higher" or "lower"? In other words, is the `<html>` element the base of a tree and everything else proceeds upward and higher or is it like the tip of a pyramid and everything else flows downward?

I realize this is a subjective question, however, I'm designing a few methods that I want to be as clear as possible to other programmers.

Comment: Just be clear in the documentation. I see it heading for the sun

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Down. The DOM API refers to child nodes — these are descendants. 'Descend' is 'to go down'. DOM events 'bubble up' the DOM from the node they originated on to the HTML element, at the top.

The only problem in the analogy lies with the 'root' element being at the top, and terminating nodes being referred to as 'leaves' (in other languages). But that's more of a poetic observation.